# Bulk import AD users from csv using powershell without user intervention

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to import users from a csv file using ADUser powershell cmdlet and here's the script

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$csvcontent = Import-CSV -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS Tools\PowerShell\AWSPowerShell\import_create_ad_users_2a.csv"

foreach ($user in $csvcontent) {
$samAccountName = $user.GivenName.substring(0,1).ToLower()+$user.LastName.ToLower()
$userPrincinpal = $samAccountName+"@mmc.local"
New-ADUser
-AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $user.Password -force)`
-ChangePasswordAtLogon $false`
-Company “mmc LLP.”`
-DisplayName ($user.GivenName+""+$user.Lastname)`
-userprincipalname $userPrincinpal`
-SamAccountName $samAccountName`    -Name ($user.GivenName+""+$user.Lastname)`
-Path “CN=Users,DC=mmc,DC=local”`
-state $user.County`
-givenname $user.GivenName`
-surname $user.Lastname`
-description ($user.Description)`
-Enabled $true`

Add-ADGroupMember "mmc_Users" $samAccountName;
}
```

But when I run the command in powershell, I get a prompt as listed below and I would like to import all the users listed in the csv file without any user intervention.

```
cmdlet New-ADUser at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Name:
```

Please review the script and let me know how to fix this.

FYI - Powershell beginner

Thanks,

Karthik

Comment: You need a backtick after New-ADUser to tell it that the command continues on the next line. Like you have backticks on those other lines.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Thank you for the response. I have a backtick infront of New-ADUser and now I get -name,-state, -DisplayName etc is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,function, script file or operable program. All the parameters after New-ADUser are not recognized.

Answer (score 2):

Backticks are generally worth avoiding. They work by escaping the next character, which on the end of a line is the newline character so it allows the command to continue. However its too easy to end up with a space after the backtick that you can't see, which then ends up getting escaped and not the newline. That doesn't seem to be the case above, but as TessellatingHeckler pointed out you were missing one after `New-ADUser`.

A better solution (to keep the code from going too far horizontal) would be to use [splatting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg675931.aspx) like this:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$csvcontent = Import-CSV -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS Tools\PowerShell\AWSPowerShell\import_create_ad_users_2a.csv"

foreach ($user in $csvcontent) {

    $samAccountName = $user.GivenName.substring(0,1).ToLower()+$user.LastName.ToLower()
    $userPrincinpal = $samAccountName+"@mmc.local"

    $NewUserParams = @{
        AccountPassword = (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $user.Password -Force)
        ChangePasswordAtLogon = $false
        Company = “mmc LLP.”
        DisplayName = ($user.GivenName+""+$user.Lastname)
        userprincipalname = $userPrincinpal
        SamAccountName = $samAccountName  
        Name = ($user.GivenName+""+$user.Lastname)
        Path = “CN=Users,DC=mmc,DC=local”
        state = $user.County
        givenname = $user.GivenName
        surname = $user.Lastname
        description = ($user.Description)
        Enabled = $true
    }

    New-ADUser @NewUserParams
    Add-ADGroupMember "mmc_Users" $samAccountName
}
```

This works by creating a hashtable `@{ }` with each of the parameters in it that you want to set and then sending that hashtable to the cmdlet with the special `@` character.

Comment: Hi Mark, 

Thank you for taking the time to respond. 

I like the way you have defined the parameters. Based on your recommendation, I tried running the script listed above and I get the following errors. Please check and let me know, what needs to be modified.

Comment: NewUserParams : The term 'NewUserParams' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS

Comment: Oh sorry should have a $ in front of it, I'll correct

Comment: NewUserParams : The term 'NewUserParams' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify

Comment: Try amended version.

Comment: Thank you for the update Mark.
New-ADUser : Directory object not found
At C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS Tools\PowerShell\AWSPowerShell\newsuers.ps1:20 char:5
+     New-ADUser @NewUserParams
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (CN=KarthikNadella...C=mmc,DC=local:String) [New-ADUser]

Comment: I think the csv file that I'm trying to import might be wrong. #wrongfromat
Any thoughts?

Comment: It's a problem with the data in your input file or how you're creating the Samaccountname. I would try outputting those variables first to check they are what you expect

Comment: Mark, 
You're absolutely right. samAccountName is not working as expected. 
$samAccountName = $user.GivenName.substring(0,1).ToLower()+$user.LastName.ToLower()
My goal is to do firstletteroffirstname+lastname and looks like that's not working as expected.

Comment: Mark, 
Have tried fixing the samAccountName but for some reason the concatenation does not work as expected. 
Here's the command and output: 
$samAccountName = ($csvcontent.GivenName.Substring(0,1))+(
$csvcontent.LastName)
Output: 
J
A
C
Terry
King
Charles

Instead of ATerry, AKing and CCharles

Please assist.Thank you!!

Comment: You should submit this as a new question as it would very helpful to see some sample data from your CSV

Comment: Mark, 

Like you suggested, I have started a new post.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44871764/ad-samaccountname-scripting-error

"Thanks" "1"

Answer (score 0):

Few things that I think look wrong, but lets try to fix it. Changing the name is best done after the user has been created. This will limit the script from failing. 
Backticks can be used for someone who is just learning how to code and it allows you to see the code in a more logical way. You could also create an array as suggested, but that can get complicated and not give correct results.

Lets break down the script below. First we call ActiveDirectory Module, then we call the CSV. That part works great.

We can test it by using the following code that was provided:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$csvcontent = Import-CSV -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS Tools\PowerShell\AWSPowerShell\import_create_ad_users_2a.csv"
$csvcontent | Out-GridView
```

This should display something with your raw data, but an example is:

GivenName | LastName | Password | Description | Country

Karthik | CSVScript  | 79HKJ#p8 | UserTest | Norway

Once we can confirm that the columns are correct. We can run the script

When you use the Import-CSV it imports the columns that you defined as a pipline($_.GivenName). This allows us not to create another variable. Calling it from the Import-CSV cmdlet will only use the fields that you provide in the raw data(CSV file).

You can save the following as a PS_Script called something like NewUser_CSV.ps1

The script below will only look at what you put into the columns. If something is not correct, that means the data in the CSV is wrong. This is a basic add AD users using a CSV file with no major error handling.

We will use the Transcript cmdlet to gather a log

```
#RUN AS ADMIN!
Start-Transcript -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS Tools\PowerShell\AWSPowerShell\import_create_ad_users_2a.log"
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$csvcontent = Import-CSV -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS Tools\PowerShell\AWSPowerShell\import_create_ad_users_2a.csv"
$csvcontent | ForEach-Object {
$sam = $_.GivenName.substring(0,1)+$_.Lastname
$setpass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $_.Password -force
 Try
 {
 New-ADUser $samAccountName `
 -Path "CN=_s,DC=mmc,DC=local" `
 -GivenName $_.GivenName `
 -Surname $_.LastName `
 -UserPrincipalName ($samAccountName + "@mmc.local")`
 -DisplayName ($_.GivenName + " " + $_.LastName) `
 -Description $_.Description `
 -Enabled $TRUE `
 -Company "mmc LLP." `
 -State $_.Country `
 -AccountPassword $setpass `
 -ChangePasswordAtLogon $False `
 -AccountPassword $setpass 

  $newdn = (Get-ADUser $samAccountName).DistinguishedName
            Rename-ADObject -Identity $newdn -NewName ($_.GivenName + " " + $_.LastName)
 }
  Catch
{
 Write-Host "[ERROR]`t Oops, something went wrong: $($_.Exception.Message)`r`n"
}
}
Stop-Transcript
```

I really hope this helps you out and gets the task done for you. Good luck with learning PowerShell.

Comment: Zack,

You're awesome. The code is working as expected. 

If your ever is DC the first beer is on me :)

"+1" "Thanks"