# AD samAccountname scripting error

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to input a csv file, which contains Givename & Lastname information of the users. When I run the command listed below samAccountName does not give me the expected output.

Please see below and let me know what should be corrected.

Input:

```
GivenName,LastName,Password,TargetOU,Description,Manager
Jeffrey,Terry,Pass12,"OU=Users,DC=mmc,DC=local",mmc user,knadella
A,King,Pass13,"OU=Users,DC=mmc,DC=local",mmc user,knadella
Chris ,Charles,Pass14,"OU=Users,DC=mmc,DC=local",mmc user,knadella
```

Command:

```
$samAccountName = ($csvcontent.GivenName.Substring(0,1))+( $csvcontent.LastName)
```

Current Output:

```
J A C Terry King Charles
```

Desired Output:

```
ATerry, AKing and CCharles
```

Please assist.Thank you!!

Comment: from where is the J A C? can you show few csv lines example?

Comment: GivenName LastName Password TargetOU Description Manager
Jeffrey Terry Pass12 OU=Users,DC=mmc,DC=local mmc user knadella
A King Pass13 OU=Users,DC=mmc,DC=local mmc user knadella
Chris Charles Pass14 OU=Users,DC=mmc,DC=local mmc user knadella

Comment: Any thoughts @Avshalom ?

Comment: added an answer, good luck

Comment: I have related question , i am beginner though . ....If there are subdomains (childa,abc.com childb.abc.com, childc.abc.com )and contains same samaccountname(123456789) how the AD is gonna do authentication ?? Is it going to check the subdomains one by one so that user can be authenticated ?? my app uses only samaccountname as login id. What is the password is different for this samaccount in each of the subdomain... ??

Answer (score 1):

You are aggregating all of the details in one go, combining the results of the `GivenName`column (`J A C`) with the results of the `LastName` column (`Terry King Charles`)`

This loops over each user:

```
foreach($user in $csvcontent){
    [array]$samAccountName += $user.GivenName[0] + $user.LastName
}
```

Output:

```
JTerry AKing CCharles
```

Comment: Thank you @gms0ulman !! 

Here's what I have done. 
1. $csvcontent = Import-CSV -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS
 Tools\PowerShell\AWSPowerShell\import_create_ad_users_2a.csv"
2. $samAccountName += $user.GivenName[0] + $user.LastName
3. $samAccountName

PS C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS Tools\PowerShell\AWSPowerShell> $samAccountName o/p only gives me the firstname and not firstnameinitial+lastname

Jeffrey
A
Baker

Comment: @Karthik Did you use a `foreach`, and cast as `[array]`? I don't see it in your code. Open the CSV file in Excel or similar and confirm it is properly formatted, with the values in the columns they should be.

Answer (score 0):

Going to give you what I use about 30 times a day. The way you are looking to create it will break some login options.

```
# <FirstLetterGivingName><LastName> for example
# WGates (William Gates)
 $sam = $_.GivenName.substring(0,1)+$_.Lastname
```

That is a good thing, but as the company grows, you will start to run into an issue where the usernames are the same. This is not a perfect solution, but having GivenName (0,3) will give you the first three letters. This will usually fix this issue. It is really rare if you hit someone with the same first three letters and lastname, but it could happen.

```
$sam = $_.GivenName.substring(0,3)+$_.Lastname
```

I have also seen companies do this, but advise not to do this, because it would be hard for the user to remember the login.

```
$sam = $_.GivenName.substring(0,1)+$_.Lastname.substring(0,7)
```

This script has been used thousands of times, but has been edited a little for this post.

```
#Test to make sure your output looks correct
#You can do this by running the following:
#Import-csv ".\import_create_ad_users.csv" | Out-GridView

# ERROR REPORTING ALL
Set-StrictMode -Version latest
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

#----------------------------------------------------------
#STATIC VARIABLES
#----------------------------------------------------------

$path = Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
$newpath = $path + ".\import_create_ad_users.csv"
$log = $path + ".\create_ad_users.log"
$date = Get-Date
$i = 1
#$addn = (Get-ADDomain).DistinguishedName
#$dnsroot = (Get-ADDomain).DNSRoot
$DNdom = Get-ChildItem -Path Ad:\ | where {$_.Name -eq "Configuration"}            
$addn = ($DNdom.DistinguishedName -split "," ,2)[1] 
$wmiDomain = Get-WmiObject Win32_NTDomain -Filter "DnsForestName = '$( (Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem).Domain)'"
$dnsroot = $wmiDomain.DomainName  + ".local"

#----------------------------------------------------------
#START FUNCTIONS
#----------------------------------------------------------
Function Start-Commands
{
  Create-Users
}

Function Create-Users
{
  "Processing started (on " + $date + "): " | Out-File $log -append
  "--------------------------------------------" | Out-File $log -append
  Import-CSV $newpath | ForEach-Object {
      If (($_.GivenName -eq "") -Or ($_.LastName -eq ""))
      {
        Write-Host "[ERROR]`t Please provide valid GivenName and LastName. Processing skipped for line $($i)`r`n"
        "[ERROR]`t Please provide valid GivenName and LastName. Processing skipped for line $($i)`r`n" | Out-File $log -append
      }
      Else
       {

        # Replace dots / points (.) in names, because AD will error when a 
        # name ends with a dot (and it looks cleaner as well)
        $replace = $_.Lastname.Replace(".","")
        If($replace.length -lt 4)
            {
            $lastname = $replace
            }
        Else
            {
            $lastname = $replace.substring(0,4)
            }
        # Create sAMAccountName according to this 'naming convention':
        # <FirstLetterInitialGivingName><LastName> for example
        # WGates (William Gates)
        $sam = $_.GivenName.substring(0,1)+$_.Lastname
        Try   { $exists = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(sAMAccountName=$sam)" }
        Catch { }
        If(!$exists)
            {
          # Set all variables according to the table names in the Excel 
          # sheet /import CSV. The names can differ in every project, but 
          # if the names change, make sure to change it below as well.
          $setpass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $_.Password -force

          Try
          {
            Write-Host "[INFORMATION]`t User is now being built : $($sam)"
            "[INFORMATION]`t User is now being built : $($sam)" | Out-File $log -append
            New-ADUser $sam -path $_.TargetOU -GivenName $_.GivenName -Initials $_.Initials `
            -Surname $_.LastName -UserPrincipalName ($sam + "@" + $dnsroot) -DisplayName ($_.GivenName + " " + $_.LastName) `
            -Description $_.Description -Manager $_.Manager -AccountPassword $setpass -Enabled $TRUE -ChangePasswordAtLogon $TRUE
            Write-Host "[INFORMATION]`t Created a new user named : $($sam)"
            "[INFORMATION]`t Created new user named: $($sam)" | Out-File $log -append

             $dn = (Get-ADUser $sam).DistinguishedName

            # Rename the object to a good looking name
            $newdn = (Get-ADUser $sam).DistinguishedName
            Rename-ADObject -Identity $newdn -NewName ($_.GivenName + " " + $_.LastName)
            Write-Host "[INFORMATION]`t Renamed the user $($sam) to $($_.GivenName) $($_.LastName)`r`n"
            "[INFORMATION]`t Renamed the user $($sam) to $($_.GivenName) $($_.LastName)`r`n" | Out-File $log -append

          }
          Catch
          {
            Write-Host "[ERROR]`t Oops, something went wrong: $($_.Exception.Message)`r`n"
          }
        }
        Else
        {
          Write-Host "[SKIP]`t User $($sam) ($($_.GivenName) $($_.LastName)) already exists or returned an error!`r`n"
          "[SKIP]`t User $($sam) ($($_.GivenName) $($_.LastName)) already exists or returned an error!" | Out-File $log -append
        }
      }
    Else
    {
      Write-Host "[SKIP]`t User ($($_.GivenName) $($_.LastName)) will be skipped for processing!`r`n"
      "[SKIP]`t User ($($_.GivenName) $($_.LastName)) will be skipped for processing!" | Out-File $log -append
    }
    $i++
  }
  "Processing ended (on " + $date + "): " | Out-File $log -append
  "--------------------------------------------" + "`r`n" | Out-File $log -append
}


Write-Host "***************************SCRIPT HAS STARTED***************************"
Write-Host "***************************SCRIPT HAS STARTED***************************"
Write-Host "***************************SCRIPT HAS STARTED***************************`r`n"
Start-Commands
Write-Host "***************************SCRIPT HAS FINISHED***************************"
Write-Host "***************************SCRIPT HAS FINISHED***************************"
Write-Host "***************************SCRIPT HAS FINISHED***************************"
```

Your CSV would have the following headers:

GivenName   LastName    LoginName   Description     Password    Manager TargetOU

Comment: Hi Zack, 

Thank you very much for helping me out here.

I have tried the script that you provided me and when I try to run the ps1 file, I don't see anything happening here. Tried looking for the log file but don't see that getting generated and at the same time I don't see any error message. 

PS C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS Tools\PowerShell\AWSPowerShell> .\newadusers.ps1
PS C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS Tools\PowerShell\AWSPowerShell>

Comment: I have a similar post that I have opened yesterday. Please check
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44856822/bulk-import-ad-users-from-csv-using-powershell-without-user-intervention "1"

Comment: @Karthik, If you are using the script above it will only find the CSV that is located inside the path the PS1 script is placed. The log would have been created in the same place.

You will need to replace this section of the above code to provide the CSV location. 
$newpath = $path + ".\import_create_ad_users.csv"

Comment: I have related question , i am beginner though . ....If there are subdomains (childa,abc.com childb.abc.com, childc.abc.com )and contains same samaccountname(123456789) how the AD is gonna do authentication ?? Is it going to check the subdomains one by one so that user can be authenticated ?? my app uses only samaccountname as login id. What is the password is different for this samaccount in each of the subdomain... ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to itterate each item and not the whole array at once:

```
$samAccountName = $csvcontent | % {
($_.GivenName.Substring(0,1))+($_.LastName)
}
```